# Marshal const char **

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm writing an extension for Arma 3. Normally you can simply write a C++ library for this and just implement this function

```
int __stdcall RVExtensionArgs(char *output, int outputSize, const char *function, const char **args, int argCnt);
```

I'm developing a C# library and I want to implement this function into it. The function `RVExtensionArgs` has a decorated name which is `_RVExtensionArgs@20` for 32-bit and `RVExtensionArgs` for 64-bit

I'm struggling with the pointer to the pointer of the const char of the args argument. My current implemention is

```
#if WIN64
    [DllExport("RVExtensionArgs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
#else
    [DllExport("_RVExtensionArgs@20", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
#endif
    public static int RvExtensionArgs(StringBuilder output, int outputSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string function,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] args,
        int argCount)
```

The DllExport used is from [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)

There is some information regarding extensions over [here](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Extensions)

But this way the game crashes. I'm quite sure that this is because of the args but I can't verify it. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you get any exception messages at all?

Comment: Sadly no, there is no useful debugging information. I can't debug anything in this case because the dll is loaded from the game and the game of course can't be debugged. I also implemented the normal RVExtension (can be found on the wiki page I linked) and this works fine.

Comment: Would it not be simpler and more performant to just import it into an unsafe class as byte* output, int outputSize, byte* function, byte** args, int argCnt to take the guesswork out of the marshaling?  The only "challenge" would be converting the UTF-16 characters in your .NET strings into bytes.

Comment: @hoodaticus I'm open for every solution I get. Can you give me some more information on how to implement your idea?

Comment: you just add unsafe to the method declaration and you can use pointers: `public unsafe static int` [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx)

Comment: Wait - why are you specifying WINAPI calling convention when you are using stdcall in C++?

Comment: @hoodaticus I modified a working example published somewhere on the internet but I already tried stdcall and it doesn't fixed the issue

Comment: Try changing the signature of the export to the C++-friendly signature I gave you.  The parameters are byte* output, int outputSize, byte* function, byte** args, int argCnt and then make sure you export as StdCall.

Comment: @hoodaticus Yeah I did and it works fine! I just have to figure out how to convert the byte** to a string array

Comment: It's an array of byte* and you are given the number of them in the last parameter.  So just use array syntax against args like args[0] for the first one.  Then call Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args[x], length) on each element of args to get the managed strings.

Comment: Oh and if you need to get the length of each native string to pass into the UTF8 call just do a for loop over *args[x][y] where x is the string index and y is the character index, and increment a counter until you hit the null character to count the non-null characters.

Comment: @chris579 - I will do that and update you.

Comment: @chris579 - please see the updated answer where I have provided a facility for marshaling byte** to string[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this in the comments to the question but want to point out that the simplest way to export `const char**` from C# to C++ is as a `byte**`.

I have created the below StringMarshaller class to help you convert byte** to string[].  I have not tested it yet - I may have time to later and will update if so.

```
public unsafe static class StringMarshaller
{
    public static string[] Marshal(byte** nativeStrings, int stringCount)
    {
        var strings = new string[stringCount];

        for (var x = 0; x < stringCount; ++x)
        {
            if (nativeStrings[x] == null) continue;
            var length = GetStringLength(nativeStrings[x]);
            strings[x] = length == 0 
                    ? string.Empty 
                    : Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nativeStrings[x], length);
        }

        return strings;
    }

    public static int GetStringLength(byte* nativeString) 
    {
        var length = 0;

        while (*nativeString != '\0')
        {
            ++length;
            ++nativeString;
        }

        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out that I'll have to use CallingConvention.Winapi or the dll is not recognized and loaded. I proposed an edit because your current example doesn't works :)

Comment: @chris579 - sorry, the review board got to your edit before I did and rejected it.  I'm not sure exactly why your change was necessary but the important thing is you got it working.  Are you good now?

Comment: The edit was needed because Encoding.UTF8.GeString can't handle the byte pointer directly. It has to be marshaled to a byte array first. But it's fine now

Comment: @chris579 - Ahh, you must be on .NET 4.0 or earlier.  The latest versions do accept raw byte pointers in a GetString overload.  BTW - congratulations on getting through this!  That was not an easy problem - you should be proud.

Comment: Well, I'm on 4.5 and the compiler throw some errors on me. Nvm, it works now and this is the main point. Thanks for the compliments, normally I don't have big issues with C# but when it comes to exporting and importing and dll interfaces I'm quite overstrained